# Sorting empty values last sytax with multiple CASE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have quite a simple ORDER BY clause that orders based on a couple of variables:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'asc' THEN emp.FirstName END asc,
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'desc' THEN emp.FirstName END desc
```

The issue I have with this is that when emp.FirstName is empty it comes first in the ordering. To fix this I have tried to introduce another case however I cannot seem to get the syntax working with more than one case.

This is the current version of the ORDER BY:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'asc' THEN CASE WHEN emp.FirstName = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, emp.FirstName asc,
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'desc' THEN CASE WHEN emp.FirstName = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, emp.FirstName desc
```

As stated this has a syntax error on the first END.

Comment: Did you try to use `ELSE` in your `CASE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to substitute a value.  A reasonable solution is:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'asc' THEN COALESCE(emp.FirstName, 'ZZZ') END asc,
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'desc' THEN COALESCE(emp.FirstName, 'ZZZ') END desc
```

A better value than `'ZZZ'` is `'~'` because that is a really big ASCII value.

Note:  If you have different collations, other values may be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used 'ZZZ' and it worked perfectly. Interestingly using '~' bought all of the empty records to the beginning again.

Comment: @CBreeze . . . That's curious about `~`.  `{` is the character immediately following `z`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND emp.FirstName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC, 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'asc' THEN emp.FirstName END asc,
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'desc' THEN emp.FirstName END desc
```

Comment: The OP say: _The issue I have with this is that when emp.FirstName is empty it comes first in the ordering_ **Not** `Null`, he mean `('')` I think.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing data types too. Your inner `CASE` returns an `int`, where as the `outer` will return a `varchar` in the `ELSE` clause.  I think the problem, however, might be solved by using an `ISNULL`. This is a **guess** however, due to lack of sample and expected results:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'asc' THEN ISNULL(emp.FirstName,'zzzzzzz') END asc,
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'desc' THEN ISNULL(emp.FirstName,'zzzzzzzz') END desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `reverse` make script more interesting

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'asc' THEN emp.FirstName 
    else reverse(emp.FirstName) END asc
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get a field for sorting-fallback?

---

Uses OwnerName if not null, otherwise First Name

[image]

There you go :)

**Copy-Paste example**

```
SET @sortCol = 'OwnerName', @sortDir = 'DESC'; 

Select
    tmp.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        NULL as OwnerName,
        '2' as FirstName
    UNION SELECT 
       '5' as OwnerName,
        '4' as FirstName
    UNION SELECT 
       '1' as OwnerName,
        '6' as FirstName
    ) tmp
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN
        @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'ASC'
    THEN
        CASE WHEN
            OwnerName IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            OwnerName
        ELSE
            FirstName
        END
    END ASC,
    CASE WHEN
        @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'DESC'
    THEN
        CASE WHEN
            OwnerName IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            OwnerName 
        ELSE
            FirstName       
        END 
    END DESC
```

Comment: my bad, title says "last" sorry :D - ill keep my solution, is an option aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
CREATE TABLE T(
    FirstName VARCHAR(45)
    );

DECLARE @sortCol VARCHAR(45) = 'OwnerName';
DECLARE @sortDir VARCHAR(5) = 'asc';

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('One'),
('Two'),
(''),
(NULL),
('Three'),
('Four');

SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'asc' THEN IIF(FirstName = '' OR FirstName IS NULL, 'ZZZZZZZZ', FirstName) END asc,
    CASE WHEN @sortCol = 'OwnerName' AND @sortDir = 'desc' THEN IIF(FirstName = '' OR FirstName IS NULL, 'ZZZZZZZZ', FirstName) END desc;
```

While you said: *The issue I have with this is that when emp.FirstName is empty it comes first in the ordering*, I think you better check for `EmptyString` ('') OR `NULL` too.

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/SNPQN77367)**